# How to not clear form on submit using WPForms

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how to not clear the form on submit when using WPForms (Wordpress). I have hooked in custom processing on submit and I want to just leave the form up on the page, and ajax process the input, and not clear the form on completion (so the user can submit again easily on any error).

Comment: Are you using any plugin? If so, could you provide the link? I think you should look into the javascript code. I believe it's an ajax submit?

Comment: Yes, ajax submit...it's the WPForms plugin (very common one)...can't find this discussed anywhere though. https://wpforms.com/

Comment: "so the user can submit again easily on any error" - does the form get cleaned even when there is a validation error? It believes it should not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to make changes to the code, you could consider returning the input value which has been submitted to be displayed in the input field... I have extracted some code from the woocommerce form-login.php as an example:

```
<input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
```

If you input a value for username, hit submit, and the form returns for any reason to that same page, the last entered value would be displayed in that input field.